# Rails Use CDN in Development ONLY For Images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, cdn

I am trying to configure my Rails app to load images from a CDN in **development** (I already know how to do it in production). I have tried messing around with the asset pipeline a bit and have found a way to reference the external images in the same structure as the production environment. The only caveat is that all of my assets in development now have the prefix of 'images' whereas I would like to only adjust the prefix for images.

Is that possible? Is there a better way to do this?

```
#config/environments/development.rb:

config.assets.prefix = "/images"

config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new do |source|
  case source
  when /\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.svg/
    "https://mycdn.com/"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `prefix` into the `asset_host`:

```
#config/environments/development.rb:

config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new do |source|
  case source
  when /\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.svg/
    "https://mycdn.com/images"
  end
end
```